# Cannot properly require c-common-init and other c-mode functions

Tags: emacs, cc-mode

This must've happened during the last month or two. I'm not sure who's to blame for it, but now when I'm trying to byte-compile a mode derived from c-mode, Emacs can't find any of c-mode functions referenced in the derived mode.
I've looked into cc-bytecom.el and (I'm not sure if it is new, but looks like it is) it defines two macros: `cc-requre` and `cc-provide`. I can't really understand what they are doing, but they seem to prevent Emacs from finding out that these functions must be available. If, in my code, I try to substitute `(requre 'cc-mode)` to `(cc-requre 'cc-mode)` nothing changes.

The said macros only seem to apply to the compilation time, but I can't tell for sure, they also call `(eval-when-compile (cc-bytecomp-restore-environment))` and `(eval-when-compile (cc-bytecomp-load (symbol-name ,cc-part)))`. I'm having hard time figuring what does it do.

Comment: This part of cc-mode is a real mess, indeed.  Worse of all, its sole purpose (pretty much) seems to be to silence byte-compiler warnings, but introducing lots of potential for weird breakage along the way.

Please give more precise instructions for reproducing your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see the problem you describe: when I compile the haxe-mode files, I just see a warning about several c-mode functions, saying that they may be undefined at runtime, because haxe-mode.el calls those functions but only loads the correspond files inside an `eval-when-compile`.

BTW, those warnings seem to be due to some weird code, probably copied from the infamous cc-bytecomp.  The patch below seem to result in a clean compilation:

```
=== modified file 'haxe-help.el'
--- haxe-help.el    2012-10-16 14:41:06 +0000
+++ haxe-help.el    2012-10-16 15:11:37 +0000
@@ -33,7 +33,6 @@

 ;;; Code:

-(eval-when-compile (require 'cl))
 (require 'cl)

 (defcustom haxe-help-location

=== modified file 'haxe-mode.el'
--- haxe-mode.el    2012-10-16 14:41:06 +0000
+++ haxe-mode.el    2012-10-16 15:21:23 +0000
@@ -77,7 +77,6 @@
 (require 'cc-bytecomp)
 (require 'cc-mode)
 (require 'cc-fonts)
-;; (cc-require-when-compile 'cc-langs)
 (require 'cc-langs)

 (require 'compile)
@@ -91,18 +90,6 @@
 (require 'haxe-log)
 ;; ------------------- my change -------------------------------------

-;; The language constants are needed when compiling.
-(eval-when-compile
-  (let ((load-path
-         (if (and (boundp 'byte-compile-dest-file)
-                  (stringp byte-compile-dest-file))
-             (cons (file-name-directory byte-compile-dest-file) load-path)
-           load-path)))
-    (load "cc-mode" nil t)
-    (load "cc-fonts" nil t)
-    (load "cc-langs" nil t)
-    (load "cc-bytecomp" nil t)))
-
 (eval-and-compile
   ;; Tell the language constant system about haXe and base it on Java.
   (c-add-language 'haxe-mode 'java-mode))
@@ -387,7 +374,7 @@
                   (c-fontify-types-and-refs
                       ((c-promote-possible-types t)
                        (parse-sexp-lookup-properties
-                        (cc-eval-when-compile
+                        (eval-when-compile
                           (boundp 'parse-sexp-lookup-properties))))
                     (save-restriction
                       (narrow-to-region (point) limit)
```